# Deployer stops working without error

Tags: 2013, publishing

On Tridion 2013, sometimes publishing stops, which means all publishing queues end in failed state.

Content Deployer doesn't output any ERROR log.
Content Deployer service doesn't stop(status is in 'started'), but it doesn't work.

Transporter output following message to log file while this problem is occuring.

```
2020-01-25 14:55:51,113 INFO  DestinationControllerSlotChecker - Maximum window size was exceeded, stopping transaction
2020-01-25 14:55:51,113 INFO  TransportService - Can transport for transaction: tcm:0-6367467-66560 is : false
2020-01-25 14:55:51,113 INFO  TransportService - Maximum window size was exceeded on destinations, throttling transport
2020-01-25 14:55:51,113 INFO  DestinationControllerSlotChecker - Maximum window size was exceeded, stopping transaction
```

Both Conent Deployer and Transporter is on Windows Server(Separeted machine).

What is possible cause of this problem?

How can I prevent this problem occuring?

I add some brief information.

- When this problem occurs, lots of publishing queues stuck in 'throttled' status.
- This problem occurs when many items are published(about 100,000
  items).
- When this problem occurs, following procedure soloves the problem.

  1. Stop Content Deployer.
  2. Remove files in 'incoming' directory of Content Deployer.
  3. Start Content Deployer.
  4. Stop Transporter and Publisher
  5. Remove transport files.
  6. Start Transporter and Publisher

After this procedure is done, publishing same items succeeds.
Specific item doesn't always cause this problem.

- My Content Deployer and Publisher's configuration is following.

**Content Deployer**

- WindowSize="20"
- Workers="10"
- Cleanup="true"
- Interval="2s"

**Publisher**

- Number of threads for deploying=1
- Number of threads for rendering=4

Is there any idea to improve configuration to prevent this problem?

I think Content Deployer worker is too few, publishing transaction's status will be 'throttled'. So Content Deployer is larger(20) than Publisher's threads(4).

Regards,

Comment: Since you say sometimes, could be a specific page/dcp publishing package causing this issue, could be one of the transaction statuses was throttling and blocked all the transactions and that's leading to fail all the transactions. could be timeout / long-running transaction timeout.

Comment: I will consider increase transaction timeout setting. Also I added additional information to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Maximum Window Size exceeded is triggered when the amount of in transit transactions has reached the WindowSize value, this is mainly to protect the Deployer from getting too many zip packages at once. You have not provided the exact version of Tridion 2013 and hot fix applied, (is it SP1 HR-1?) but you may need to look if you have the latest fix applied as there are several hot fixes which can help with mass publish issues. (see http://csei.sdl.com/hotfixes/#/hotfixes/c).

Another common issue is if you are using Storage extensions which can slow down the deployment process. You can try to lower the number of threads for rendering (e.g. 2) temporary to see if the publishing will be more stable.
Some additional tips on how to fix your issue can be found here:
http://megipsy.blogspot.com/2015/05/sdl-tridion-tips-to-troubleshoot-and.html